# how to limit access to api per user in wso2 api manager 4.1.0 with basic authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using from wso2 api manager 4.1.0 and I have basic authentication on my api. I want to give access specific api to specific user.

Could you please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your backend is secured with basic authentication. If that is the case, you can follow the documentation to add endpoint security and fulfil your requirement. Please refer the documentation. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/endpoints/endpoint-security/basic-auth/.

Or else if you want to add basic auth security from api manager, you can follow the doc, https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-basic-authentication/#enabling-basic-authentication-for-an-api.